# How to get url just clicked before confirm popup comes in angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-ui-router

I am new to angular 4. I have multiple tabs in one page, when I switch from one tab to another or to other nav bar, my requirement is to provide a popup dialog which asked "are you sure to move ?" and when I pressed ok , it should go to desired tab/nav (last clicked url) otherwise it should remain at the same page.

I have used  CanDeactivateGuard , to popup the dialog before i leave the tab/switch to other nav bar `{ path: 'exception/:id', component: LpExceptionComponent , canDeactivate: [CanDeactivateGuard]}`

Now I am not sure how to redirect to desired tab on pressing ok button?
how I will get the last clicked url here?

Comment: Are you having the tabs in the router. If so I'll give you a solution by tomorrow cause I have them implemented. Please reply to this comment so I don't forget :) :)

Comment: Yes, tabs are in router.I used the canDeactivate function and able to get the nextStateUrl as well on new dialog, but  after clicking on ok button of that dialog, not able to navigate to nextStateUrl. not sure why it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't even need to know the url. You can just return a promise from the canDeactivate function, and once the user clicks ok, you resolve the promise to true and the transition continues automatically. Observables are also supported if you prefer that over promises.

But if you do need to know the state that the user is trying to go to, then it's provided as the fourth parameter to the canDeactivate function (the first three parameters being component, currentRoute, and currentState)

See documentation here: https://angular.io/api/router/CanDeactivate

Comment: Thanks Nicholas! I have used the fourth parameter of the canDeactivate function and able to get the state user is trying to go but not able to navigate to this url on click of ok.  Just not sure why router navigation is not working on that dialog only